# SQLAlchemy, How can I create a custom compilation that is context aware

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I would like to be able to compile an SQLAlchemy query in to SQL query in different ways; how can I compile  **distinct count** differently from **count**?

When I have select count

```
sql.select([sql.func.count(c1)]).select_from(t1)
```

the result should be

```sql
select count(c1) from t1
```

But when I have count distinct, for example

```
sql.select([sql.func.count(c1.distinct())]).select_from(t1)
```

the result should be

```sql
select count(1) from t1 ;
```

Comment: @IljaEverilä it is just an example , i'm actually replacing this with a totaly other function that return an integer , but is specific to my DB
but u can use this for debugging and performance measurement
as u mention, there was a mistake in my query , i update the query.

Answer (score 2):

In order to match `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)` you need to override compiling `Function`:

```
import copy

from sqlalchemy import func

from sqlalchemy.ext.compiler import compiles

from sqlalchemy.sql import operators
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import literal, Function, UnaryExpression

@compiles(Function)
def visit_function(f, compiler, **kw):
    clauses = f.clauses.clauses

    if f.name.lower() == 'count' \
            and len(clauses) == 1 \
            and isinstance(clauses[0], UnaryExpression) \
            and clauses[0].operator is operators.distinct_op:
        f = func.count(1)

    return compiler.visit_function(f, **kw)
```